# Apache Homebrew does not start on MacOS: No Path for Address

Tags: macos, apache, path, homebrew, timemachine

I'm having an issue with Homebrew Apache after using TimeMachine to transfer my system to another computer.

When I terminal "sudo apachectl start" I get this notification in the system.log:

> httpd[4212]: no path for address 0x10ed15000

When I terminal "brew services start httpd24" I get:

> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.httpd24[4370]): Service exited
>   with abnormal code: 1

When I terminal "sudo apachectl configtest" I get:

> Syntax OK

There are no apache logs because it doesn't start. Homebrew tells me Httpd24 is running, however, it doesn't show in the Activity Monitor.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here, suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is different between the 2 systems in terms of hardware and OS versions?

Comment: New: MacOS Sierra 10.12.5, 2.8Ghz i7, 8GB Memory
Original: MacOS Sierra 10.12.4, 2.7Ghz i5, 8GB Memory

Comment: Um, Because you restored the contents on top of any running OS, you'll face this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/583

Comment: First, "Brew Update" works fine. Second, it was a formatted laptop

Comment: Oh so you updated Sierra *after* you restored the backup.

Comment: I would assume that to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Tried a million things, the only way I was able to get Apache back up and running was to:

1. Remove Homebrew
2. Install Homebrew